# Grammar error in new user banner message

Tags: bug, status-completed

The banner message for new/not-logged-in users reads

> Welcome to Q&A site for expert programmers interested...

There should be an article in there:

> Welcome to a Q&A site for...

Or, if we want to be fancier:

> Welcome to the super-mega-ultimate best-on-the-Interblags programmer Q&A site!!!!eleven!!

Reference image (ignore the freehand text, I'm reusing an earlier screenshot (hey, I'm being "green")) available [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65401/limit-the-size-of-banner-messages).

Comment: You might want to post this on the main meta; it appears wrong in general, not just here

Comment: Holy crap, I never noticed that before...

Comment: @Michael, thanks, I never bothered to check the other sites.

Comment: @TheLQ, not surprising. This looks like the most common error I make, the "I decided to tweak the wording but waffled on how to do it and after some copy-and-pasting I got the general idea right but an article or preposition got left out somewhere along the way." Check out the screenshot of the banner at [this recent question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63226/show-system-message-banner-when-not-logged-in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It now says

> Welcome to Q&A for expert programmers interested in professional discussions on software development -- check out the FAQ!